# Allow a field in a form to accept multiple values

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with a many-to-many relationship.  Three of the tables are:

-Player

-PlayerPreviousClubs ***(Lookup Table)***

-PreviousClubs

Then I have a form.  Below is an extract:

```
<form action="?<?php htmlout($action); ?>" method="post">

<div>
<label for="previousclubs">Previous Clubs: <input type="text" name="previousclubs"
id="previousclubs" value="<?php htmlout($previousclubs); ?>"></label>
</div>

</form>
```

I do not know how many previous clubs will be created per profile.  It will range from 0 to x.

I could set up say 5 separate fields for previous club entries, but this is kind of messy.  There may be too many, there may not be enough and it is not a 'clean' solution.

How do I cater for this functionality in my form?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would add a button that triggers some JavaScript that adds another input field, so the user can control how many values can be inserted. By changing the name(s) of the input fields to `previousclubs[]` you can collect the values as an array, no matter how many values there are.

Answer (score 0):

enter each previous clubs and separate with comma or semicolon then when you submit use

```
$previousclubsArray = explode(','$_POST['previousclubs']);// if you used comma to seperate the items
```

so you have each previous clubs records as elements of the $previousclubArray and you can save in the appropriate table.